# Basic R - how to exclude rows with blank columns, how to show data for specific column values

Tags: r

Two questions about R:
1.) If I have a data set with the multiple column values and one of the column values is 'test_score' how can I exclude the rows with blank values (and / or non-numeric values) for that column? (using pie(), hist(), or cor())

2) If the dataset has a column named 'Teachers', how might I graph the column 'testscores' only for the rows where Teacher = Jones?

Creating separate vectors without the missing data:

```
dat.nomissing <- tenthgrade[!is.nan(Score),]
```

seems problematic as the two columns must remain paired.
I was thinking something such as:

```
hist(!is.nan(tenthgrade$Score)[tenthgrade$Teacher=='Jones'])
```

However, is.nan is creating a list of TRUE, FALSE values (as it should).

Comment: Show the data, or a mock replicate of it.

Comment: I'd check out one of the manuals that comes with R: http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html. Or peruse the R questions here on SO, all of these things have been answered in detail recently.

Comment: I posted the question to Super User as I felt it would be out of place here. It seemed a bit too basic and I felt I should know how to do it with the info at hand... but didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subscripting. For example:

```
dat[!is.na(dat$test_score),]
hist(dat$test_score[dat$Teachers=='Jones'])
```

And a more complete example with artificial data:

```
# Create artificial dataset
dat <- data.frame('test_score'=rnorm(500), 'Teachers'=sample(c('Jones', 'Smith', 'Clark'), 500, replace=TRUE))   

# Introduce some random missingness
dat$test_score[sample(1:500, 50)] <- NA  

# Keep if test_score is valid                                                                      
dat.nomissing <- dat[!is.na(dat$test_score),]   

# Plot subset of data                                          
 hist(dat$test_score[dat$Teachers=='Jones'])
```